# Reorient data so row values are row columns

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have tried to transform my data but can't seem to make it work.

Here is a reproducible sample of my data:

```
structure(list(BreedingSeason = c("2017-2018", "2018-2019", "2016-2017", 
"2014-2015", "2017-2018", "2017-2018"), Nest = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), HubDist = c(828.4829,3125.2952, 1433.3238, 1539.5785, 
1602.5289, 1431.7102)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I have right now:

[image: Current data]

And I simply want to make a table that looks like this:

| BreedingS | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-2021 | 1609.11 | 1564.3043 |
| 2020-2021 | 4502.2435 | N/A |
| 2019-2020 | 5583.4196 | 1615.0845 |

etc. It is for a Wilcox test, just trying to compare the distances in group 1 with group 0, the breeding season is just incase I want to filter the data by breeding season and redo the test.

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of your data with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Apologies, I have now done that

Comment: Thanks, in your sample we only have `0` values for `Nest` and it would be much better you just present a sample with all the unique values of `Nest`. You could include for example more of your observations.

Comment: My bad - I've corrected it.

Comment: @BurtonGuster Looks like you might want to use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) might be helpful for you.